# How do i 'replace' an array by filling an empty array's elements using pop method from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack in python and I'm experimenting with the `list` data structure. If i want to use the pop method to 'fill' an empty array by using the elements from *an existing array*, what do I do?

```
# Implementing Stacks in Python through the given list structure


practiceStack = []

practiceStack.append(['HyunSoo', 'Shah'])
practiceStack.append('Jack')
practiceStack.append('Queen')
practiceStack.append(('Aces'))

# printing every element in the list/array
for i in practiceStack:
    print(i)

# since stacks are LIFO (last in first out) or FILO (first in last out), the pop method will remove the first thing we did

emptyArrayPop = []
```

This is what I tried (by using a for loop) and keep getting a `use integers not list` error

```
for i in practiceStack:
    emptyArrayPop[i].append(practiceStack.pop)

print(emptyArrayPop)
```

Comment: Did you mean `practiceStack.pop()`?

Comment: There is no such error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `pop` function is a function — not a value. In other words, `practiceStack.pop` is a *pointer* to a function (you can mostly ignore this until you've spent more time around code); you likely want this instead:

```
practiceStack.pop()
```

You also need to append to the *list*; when adding something with `append`, the List will automatically add it at the end; you do not need to provide an index.

Further explanation: **The List.append method will take the value that you pass to it and add that to the end of the List.** For example:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3]
A.append(4)
```

`A` is now `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If you try to run the following:

```py
A[2].append(4)
```

...then you are effectively saying, "append 4 to the end of the value at position-2 in `A`", (`A[2] is set to 3 in the above example; remember that python lists start counting at 0, or are "0-index".)  which is like saying "Append 4 to 3." This makes no sense; it doesn't mean anything to append an integer to another integer.

Instead, you want to append to the LIST itself; you do not need to specify a position.

Don't get this confused with assigning a value to a position in a List; if you were setting a value at an existing position of a list, you can use the `=` operator:

```
>>> B = [1, 2, 3]
>>> B[2]
3
>>> B[2] = 4
>>> print(B)
[1, 2, 4]
>>> B.append(8)
>>> print(B)
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

So to answer your original question, the line you want is the following:

```
emptyArrayPop.append(practiceStack.pop())
```

(note the `[i]` has been removed)

---

**[edit]** Not the only issue, as @selcuk pointed out.

You will also need to fix the way you're accessing data in the `practiceStack` list, as you cannot edit a list (calling `pop` modifies the list in-place) when you are iterating over it.

You will need to iterate over the integer index of the list in order to access the elements of `practiceStack`:

```py
for i in range(len(practiceStack)):
    emptyArrayPop.append(practiceStack.pop())
```

Comment: Did you try running this?

Comment: i actually don't follow your answer at all. i havent taken any algorithm courses, i was just watching a youtube video on recursion that involved stacks so i don't really follow what you mena. could you more slowly/elaborate your explanation? like provide more context? what do you mean pointer to this a function? what do you mean append to the list and don't need an index? 

and what do you mean cannot edit a list when iterating over it?

Comment: I would ignore the definition of a "pointer" for now (though it's a good concept to add to your queue of things to learn! I'll add a bit more explanation to my answer now.

Comment: what the hell? i changed the for loop to for i in practiceStack:
emptyArrayPop.append(practiceStack.pop) and got this message:

[<built-in method pop of list object at 0x10228fd88>, <built-in method pop of list object at 0x10228fd88>, <built-in method pop of list object at 0x10228fd88>, <built-in method pop of list object at 0x10228fd88>]

Comment: @j6m8 do you understand why i got this message? didnt i do what you did??

Comment: Make sure you include the `()` at the end of `pop()`!